# Folder wordpress page redirect

Tags: pages, redirect, htaccess, subdomains, domain-mapping

I have my wordpress on a folder, lets say /blog. I would like to be albe to redirect virtualy the users so visit some specific urls to a page. Let's say:
I have my terms page that so it is on /blog/terms
I would like that users who access directly on /terms see that page to but wihout changing the url.
This is my current rule on .htaccess to redirect to the blog

```
RewriteRule ^blog - [NC,L]
```

And this is the /blog folder .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried things like this on my htaccess without success.

```
RewriteRule ^terms$ /blog/terms [NC,L]
```

I allways got a 404, sometimes from my main domain, sometimes a "Oops! That page can’t be found." from wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the way after a lot of testing:

```
RewriteRule ^terms /blog/index.php/termspage [NC,L]
```